# How do I un-steal power armor?

Tags: fallout-4

I noticed that when I destroy enemies' fusion cores in the power armor they use, they get out, and I'm able to take it. However, most companions do not like if you steal things. I respect that, so I usually leave these power armor frames for display in my settlements. However, in order to move them around when I remodel my settlements, it counts as stealing the frame every time I enter it, which causes me to lose affinity with all of the companions I have in that settlement.

Am I doing something wrong or this a bug? I feel like it shouldn't count as stealing every time I enter it...

Comment: I've experienced the same thing, and I want to say it's a bug. I once stole power armor from the Atom Cats Garage and brought it back to my settlement where it is still considered stealing whenever I enter it (and the words are in red when I attempt to enter it)

Comment: Is there any way around it though? It does that whenever I take raider power armor.

Comment: I've read that if you take the power armor and bring it to a crafting station, take all the pieces off and place them in your inventory, the pieces become yours. You can then place them on a new frame and should be good to go. It's a work around and a nuisance since you'll need a new frame.

Comment: Ugh I have so many "stolen" frames though

Comment: @Vemonus You really only need two frames, one for you and one for your follower. Drop the rest in a river.

Comment: @DCShannon that is completely unacceptable. I **NEED** to have all 15+ power armor frames on display.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, the vanilla game treats taking or entering owned power armor as stealing, even if the previous owner is no longer among the living.

If you're on PC, you can open the console, click the power armor frame, type `ClearOwnership`, then hit enter. Also works for things like beds and all the containers in Covenant. `SetOwnership npcRefId` allows setting a specific NPC as owner. I've heard you can use it without an ID to have the same effect as `ClearOwnership`.

If you're on a console, I don't believe there's a solution to the frame itself. However, you can clear ownership of the individual parts by reverse-pickpocketing them onto a settler, then doing a normal trade to take it back. Alternately, Timmy Jim says you can just park the frame in a power armor station, remove the parts, then they're unowned.

I know there's [at least one mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/6698/?) that lets you scrap and rebuild the frames (clearing ownership in the process), but I don't believe it's been ported to console.

Comment: For those reading this in 2018 & beyond, I can clarify that the mod has in fact been ported to the console.